# Event listener within contenteditable div stops working after 1 event (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am creating text editing functionality on my site and for that I have used a contenteditable container wherein extra divs can be added which are used to enter text that requires special formatting, to insert those divs I am using the InsertHTML command. I am then using jQuery to add a keydown event which is used to change the default behavior of the tab and enter buttons, this event only seems to work once and then doesn't respond.

Here is the code I am using to insert the divs into my contenteditable container:

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, '<div class="code_edit_block" contenteditable tabindex="1">Enter text here</div><br>');
$(".code_edit_block").on("keydown",function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode===9){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "&emsp;");
        $(".code_edit_block").focus();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode===13){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<br><br>");
        $(".code_edit_block").focus();
    }
});
```

This code is called using a function, every time a button is clicked the function containing this code is called

General structure of the contenteditable container:

```
<div id="tutorial_text_edit_div" class="tutorial_text_div" contenteditable >
    user text
    <div class="code_edit_block" contenteditable tabindex="1">
        inserted formatting div with user content
    </div>
    more user text
    <div class="code_edit_block" contenteditable tabindex="1">
        inserted formatting div with user content
    </div>
</div>
```

This code has no issue on firefox, but on google chrome the event listener only fires once before it stops working, can anyone tell me why that is?